# Scala Slick ManyToMany return

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick

currently I'm trying to make a ManyToMany Request with Scala and Slick.

It works really well, but the data isn't ordered nicely

I make the request like the last example in: [ForeignKeyTest](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick-testkit/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/testkit/tests/ForeignKeyTest.scala)

The data that gets returned is a list or a set which includes a tuple.

`List((Object1, Object2-1), (Object1, Object2-2), (Object1, Object2-3), etc...)`

Thats not really good since I will always have the overhead of Object1

I would like to have something more like this:

```
List(Object1, Seq[Object2-1, Object2-2, Object2-3])
```

But I'm a scala beginner and I don't think that i could play that much with yield? is there even a way of doing so or do i need to change the output after the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, slick can not return a list containting a list.
However you can transform the result to something more usefull as follows:

```
val listOfTuples: List[A,B] = List((a1, b1), (a1, b2), (a1, b3), (a2, b4))
val map : Map[A,List[B]] = listofTuples.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

the result `map` will be equal to the following

```
Map( a1 -> List(b1,b2,b3),
  a2 -> List(b4))
```

Comment: thanks. really but i need to make a left outer join, since a inner join will return List() when A has no entries for B.

Comment: btw. i still struggle, since when i use a outer join i can't return the whole Object2.. thats somehow dumb.

Comment: Can you post your code? I do not really understand your problem